# declare in array and print the values randomly from array in bash script

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

Here is my bash script code

```
declare -a types=("m4.xlarge" "m5.12xlarge" "m5d.12xlarge" "m4.large" "m4.16xlarge" "t2.2xlarge" "c4.large" "c5.xlarge" "r4.2xlarge" "x1e.4xlarge" "h1.16xlarge" "i3.16xlarge" );
echo "array declared"


for i in {1..100}
do

for (( i=1; i<${arraylength}+1; i++ ))   
 do

#index=$( jot -r 1  0 $((${#expressions[@]} - 1)) )
    randominstancetype=$[$RANDOM % ${#types[@]}];

    #randominstancetype=$( shuf -i0-1 -n1 $((${#types[@]} )) );
    #randominstancepvtiptype=$[$RANDOM % ${#pvtip[@]}];
        #randominstancepubiptype=$[$RANDOM % ${#pubip[@]}];
done
 done
```

I am trying to declare array and then print the elements inside the array randomly for around 100 times. Currently the name of the elements are not getting displayed instead it displays as 3 5 8 etc.. Anyhelp will be appreciated.

Comment: Judging from your previous questions that are all unaccepted... If there is a satisfying answer that solves your problem, take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Note that this will give reputation not only to the answerer but also to you.

Answer (score 1):

`$[...]` is the old and deprecated version of `$((...))`. So what you are doing is just simple arithmetic expansion that expands back to the random index.

To access an element of the array **with** the generated index, use:

```
echo "${types[$RANDOM%${#types[@]}]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash  
declare -a types=("m4.xlarge" "m5.12xlarge" "m5d.12xlarge" "m4.large" "m4.16xlarge" "t2.2xlarge" "c4.large" "c5.xlarge" "r4.2xlarge" "x1e.4xlarge" "h1.16xlarge" "i3.16xlarge" )
echo "array declared"

max_random=32767
type_count=${#types[@]}
factor=$(( max_random / type_count ))

for i in {1..1000}
do
    random_index=$(( $RANDOM / $factor ))
    random_instance_type=${types[$random_index]}
    echo $random_instance_type
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This will print a randomized order of your array `types`.

```
for j in {1..100}; do
  for i in $(shuf -i 0-$((${#types[*]}-1))); do
     printf "%s " "${types[i]}";
  done;
  printf "\n";
done
```

If you would allow repetitions, then you can do

```
for j in {1..100}; do
  for i in $(shuf -n ${#types[*]} -r -i 0-$((${#types[*]}-1))); do
     printf "%s " "${types[i]}";
  done;
  printf "\n";
done
```

The commands make use of `shuf` and its options :

> - **`-n`, `--head-count=COUNT`:** output at most `COUNT` lines
> - **`-i`, `--input-range=LO-HI`:** treat each number `LO` through `HI` as an input line
> - **`-r`, `--repeat`:** output lines can be repeated
>
> <sub>**source `man shuf`**</sub>